# How to return objects grouped by in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations:

```
Approval belongs_to Ad
Ad has_many Approvals
Ad belongs_to Page
Page has_many Ads
```

I want to get all the Approvals but grouped by Page. So that later on, I can iterate over each page and print all the approvals for each ad that belong to the page.

If I try this:

```
Approval.includes(:ad).group_by('ads.page_id')
```

I get this:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "approvals.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: I don't know how to do exactly what you want. But if your main goals is to just list pages and their approvals, you can get *pages* and eager_load their ads and the ads' approvals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails isn't going to work like straight sql so you'll need to do a few things to get the desired behaviour.

First, create the query to get all the results. Something like `Page.ads.approvals` perhaps. `ads` might need to be `ad`

Secondly implement pagination for the results, preferably through a gem like will_paginate or kaminari.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ORDER BY not GROUP BY. GROUP BY is when you're going to use aggregation functions like sum() and count().

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.